# cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Olá. Estou há alguns dias tentando solucionar esse erro, mas sem sucesso.

Estou tentando importar o ProfileReport da biblioteca pandas_profiling. Consigo fazer a instalação via pip, direto do repositório no GitHub. Usando

```
#Baixando Pandas-profile

!pip install https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Em seguida, quando tento realizar importação do ProfileReport

```
#Importanto ProfileReport

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Esse erro é apresentado:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_62935/1977696158.py in <module>
      1 #Importanto ProfileReport
      2 
----> 3 from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
      7 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      8 from pandas_profiling.version import __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/controller/pandas_decorator.py in <module>
      2 from pandas import DataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      5 
      6 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/profile_report.py in <module>
     25 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core import Root
     26 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.renderable import Renderable
---> 27 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.templates import (
     28     create_html_assets,
     29 )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/html/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.alerts import HTMLAlerts
      2 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.collapse import HTMLCollapse
      3 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.container import HTMLContainer
      4 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.duplicate import HTMLDuplicate
      5 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html.frequency_table import (

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/html/alerts.py in <module>
      1 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.alerts import Alerts
----> 2 from pandas_profiling.report.presentation.flavours.html import templates
      3 
      4 
      5 class HTMLAlerts(Alerts):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/html/templates.py in <module>
      3 from pathlib import Path
      4 
----> 5 import jinja2
      6 
      7 from pandas_profiling.config import Settings, Theme

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py in <module>
     10 from .bccache import FileSystemBytecodeCache
     11 from .bccache import MemcachedBytecodeCache
---> 12 from .environment import Environment
     13 from .environment import Template
     14 from .exceptions import TemplateAssertionError

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py in <module>
     23 from .compiler import CodeGenerator
     24 from .compiler import generate
---> 25 from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
     26 from .defaults import BLOCK_START_STRING
     27 from .defaults import COMMENT_END_STRING

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py in <module>
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      2 from ._compat import range_type
----> 3 from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401
      4 from .tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS  # noqa: F401
      5 from .utils import Cycler

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py in <module>
     11 from markupsafe import escape
     12 from markupsafe import Markup
---> 13 from markupsafe import soft_unicode
     14 
     15 from ._compat import abc

ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solução

Esse erro significa que assim que importada, a versão atual do `pandas_profiling` está dependendo direta ou indiretamente do sub-modulo `soft_unicode` da lib `markupsafe`.

A versão do `markupsafe` precisa ser revertida pra uma release antes da alteração desse sub-módulo:

```bash
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

#### Investigação

Ganha-se mais sabendo como investigar um erro do que sabendo somente a solução, portanto segue um processo útil pra navegar erros do formato `cannot import certo_modulo from certa_lib`:

- Se você fez recentemente um `pip install nova_lib@x.x.x`, sua biblioteca recém-instalada (no nosso caso `pandas_profiling`) pode ser atualizada se `x.x.x` não for a versão mais recente, rodando `pip install --upgrade nova_lib`. *Sua instalação já pega a versão mais recente, então aqui não se aplica*
- Se você não pode atualizar a versão (que é o caso aqui), procure saber quando o "`certo_modulo`" foi tirado da "`certa_lib`": como o [`markupsafe` está no GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe), acessamos no menu direito [suas Releases](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/releases) e percebemos que [na versão 2.1.0 o `soft_unicode` foi deprecado e substituído pelo `soft_str`](https://markupsafe.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/#version-2-1-0):
  [image: Deprecação do soft_unicode na v2.1.0 do markupsafe]
- Chegamos à conclusão de que a versão anterior (no caso a 2.0.1 por estar listada logo antes da 2.1.0 nas Releases) é necessária para retornar nossa nova lib à normalidade.
- Noutros casos, uma pesquisa no google pode levar a uma discussão relevante do github com a solução (recomendo adicionar  `site:github.com` no final da pesquisa, restringirá seus resultados). Mesmo se o repositório da issue não for o mesmo do que você instalou, ele pode solucionar o mesmo problema, o que [pro nosso caso acontece neste comentário de fevereiro no repositório `aws-sam-cli`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661#issuecomment-1044340547).